# GetDateFormat() fails on dates before 1/1/1601

Tags: winapi, localization, internationalization

i am trying to format a date using Windows [GetDateFormat API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
nResult = GetDateFormat(
      localeId,   //0x409 for en-US, or LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT if you're not testing
      0,          //flags
      dt,         //a SYSTEMTIME structure
      "M/d/yyyy", //the format we require
      null,       //the output buffer to contain string (null for now while we get the length)
      0);         //the length of the output buffer (zero while we get the length)
```

Now we pass it a date/time:

```
SYSTEMTIME dt;
dt.wYear = 1600;
dt.wMonth = 12;
dt.wDay = 31;
```

In this case nResult returns zero:

> The function returns 0 if it does not succeed. To get extended error information, the application can call GetLastError, which can return one of the following error codes:
>
> - ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. A supplied buffer size was not large enough, or it was incorrectly set to NULL.
> - ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS. The values supplied for flags were not valid.
> - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. Any of the parameter values was invalid.

If, however, i return a date one day later:

```
SYSTEMTIME dt;
dt.wYear = 1601;
dt.wMonth = 1;
dt.wDay = 1;
```

Then it works.

What am i doing wrong? How do i format dates?

e.g. the date of [the birth of Christ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KokXbUV_SU):

```
12/25/0000
```

or [the date when the universe started](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Ussher):

```
-10/22/4004 6:00 PM
```

or the date Caesar died:

```
-3/15/44
```

---

### Bonus Reading

- **Sorting It All Out**: [GetDateFormat is Gregorian based](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/14/353216.aspx)
- [`GetDateFormatEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: There wasn't a year zero.  Jesus was nominally born on 12/25/0001.  </pedantry>

Comment: There was no October 7th in Alaska in 1867. (Nor was there October 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, or 17 that year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a limitation on [SystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`...year/month/day/hour/minute/second/milliseconds value since 1 January 1601 00:00:00 UT... to 31 December 30827 23:59:59.999`

I spent some time looking up how to get around this limitation, but since `GetDateFormat()` takes a `SystemTime` you'll probably have to bite the bullet and write your own `format()` method.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're referring to the [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, which *is* the number of `100 ns` intervals since 1/1/1601. On the other hand i do now see the documented minimums and maximums of `TIMESTAMP`. And now that i see that's it's a limitation of `TIMESTAMP` (and not of `GetDateFormat` using a Gregorian calendar), i have no choice but to look elsewhere. i was hoping elsewhere in Windows is a function to format a date in a particular locale.

Comment: Oops, you're right about the `FILETIME` being the count of `100 ns`. My eyes must have jumped a bit when reading it. The idea still stands, of course, just that `SYSTEMTIME` is displayed as a year/month/day/hour/minute/second/milliseconds value.

Answer (score 1):

[SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct is valid only from year 1601 through 30827, because in Windows machines, is system time counted from elapsed intervals from 1.1.1601 00:00. See 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) article.